# WPF Markup Control

Tags: wpf, markup

I have a string of text that I need to display.  I currently display it in a textbox.

My requirements have changed and now I need to display parts of this string in Red.

I have looked and all I can see for displaying text in several colors is a WebBrowser or RichTextbox.  Both of these are more complex then I was hoping to use.

I can format the text string in any way (using any kind of markup).

**Is there some kind of simple markup control out there for wpf?**  (Note: This will be going on a datagrid that can have many hundreds of rows, so it cannot be a memory/processing intensive control.)

Comment: How do you know what part of the text should be red? Is it by position or by a filter?

Comment: I was going to insert some kind of delimiter or markup.  I think I will just use the <Run> syntax of a TextBlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.110).aspx) if it doesn't need to be edited.

From above link:

> TextBlock is designed to be lightweight, and is geared specifically at integrating small portions of flow content into a user interface (UI). TextBlock is optimized for single-line display, and provides good performance for displaying up to a few lines of content.
>
> TextBlock is not optimized for scenarios that need to display more than a few lines of content; for such scenarios, a FlowDocument coupled with an appropriate viewing control is a better choice than TextBlock, in terms of performance. After TextBlock, FlowDocumentScrollViewer is the next lightest-weight control for displaying flow content, and simply provides a scrolling content area with minimal UI. FlowDocumentPageViewer is optimized around "page-at-a-time" viewing mode for flow content. Finally, FlowDocumentReader supports the richest set functionality for viewing flow content, but is correspondingly heavier-weight.

Modified example from link showing Red Text:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" >
        <Bold>TextBlock</Bold> is designed to be <Italic>lightweight</Italic>
              and is geared  <Run Foreground="Red">specifically</Run> at integrating 
              <Italic>small</Italic> portions of flow content into a UI.

    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AvalonEdit should do what you want. There is a Nuget package for it. See here also:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

Also, if the text is not being edited, I think you should probably use something like a ListBox with custom item templates -- especially if the entire line is to be highlighted.

Comment: I think AvalonEdit would do it.  But I think it is too heavy a control for what I need. As I said in my question, this will be going on a datagrid that can have many hundreds of rows, so it cannot be a memory/processing intensive control